# Looping JSON in Php

Tags: php

json_from_db:

```
 {
   "id": 23,
   "positions": "[{\"col\":2,\"row\":1,\"size_x\":10,\"size_y\":3}]",
   "styles": "\"position: absolute; min-width: 135px; min-height: 160px;\"",
   "created_at": "2016-07-18 02:40:36",
   "updated_at": "2016-07-18 02:40:36"
 }
```

Looping in PHP:

```
$positions = json_from_db
foreach($positions->position as $value) { echo $value->col}
```

Invalid argument supplied error

I want to get the value of col, sixe_x and size_y

**Update**

Answers below are correct, but 
want to get values of styles as well

Comment: I have updated my answer with your updated input.

Comment: all answer were correct, upvoted

Comment: @DanielleRoseMabunga you want only  col, sixe_x and size_y values from the whole array?

Comment: @DanielleRoseMabunga Thanks for the upvotes. If you used a particular answer as the basis for your solution, you should probably select it as well; not just upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Try my source xD

```
$positions = json_decode('{
"id": 6,
"positions": [
    {
        "col": 6,
        "row": 1,
        "size_x": 2,
        "size_y": 2
    }
],
"created_at": "2016-07-17 23:36:47",
"updated_at": "2016-07-17 23:36:47"
}');
echo 'col: '.$positions->positions[0]->col.'<br>';
echo 'row: '.$positions->positions[0]->row.'<br>';
echo 'size_x: '.$positions->positions[0]->size_x.'<br>';
echo 'size_y: '.$positions->positions[0]->size_y.'<br>';
```

You will get result

```
col: 6
row: 1
size_x: 2
size_y: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `json_decode()`.

```
$arr = '{"id":6,"positions":" [{\"col\":6,\"row\":1,\"size_x\":2,\"size_y\":2}]","created_at":"2016-07-17 23:36:47","updated_at":"2016-07-17 23:36:47"}';
$positionsArr = json_decode($arr,true);
$positions = json_decode($positionsArr["positions"],true);
foreach($positions as $value) 
{ 
    echo "size x:". $value['size_x']. "\n size y: ". $value['size_y'];
}
```

**Live demo : [Click Here](https://eval.in/606696)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to decode the JSON before you can work with the data

```
$json_obj = json_decode($json_from_db);
$positions = $json_obj->positions;

foreach($positions as $position){
    echo $position->col . "<br/>";
}
```

[**Live demo.**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e85cf1b24646b81821855339b3964fe51eb2f3d9)